# Thread safe log class which creates log files according to the current date when entry was added

Tags: c#, beginner, multithreading, logging

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195084/thread-safe-logging-class-implementation#) and some help I created a thread safe logging class on which the name of the log file is same as the current date (short date) when the log entry was added. e.g. If I create ten entries today say they will all get written to log file named "07.10.2015.txt". I want to use this class from DLL.
I am curious on your opinion if this is reasonable and **thread safe** class?

```
public static class Logger
{
    static readonly object _syncObject = new object();

    public static void Write(string logMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            var todaysLogFilePath = Path.Combine(ConfigManager.GetAppSetting("logPath"), 
                                                    ("Log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd") + ".txt"));
            Log(logMessage, todaysLogFilePath);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //log somewhere else if required
        }
    }

    static void Log(string logMessage, string logFilePath)
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, 
                        string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", 
                        DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), logMessage));
        }
    }
}
```

PS. I don't want third party classes because they have some [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273377/how-to-use-nlog-for-a-dll) sometimes if used from DLL which is my requirement, and in some cases I don't know directly how to enable in those classes ability to name the log entries same as the current date when log was added.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> static readonly object _syncObject = new object();
> ```

You should always add a scope identifier because it increases readability.

> ```
> var todaysLogFilePath = Path.Combine(ConfigManager.GetAppSetting("logPath"), 
>                                         ("Log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd") + ".txt"));
> Log(logMessage, todaysLogFilePath);
> ```

Each time the `Write()` method is called you are

- reading from the config to get the logging path
- construct a new filepath

I know why you are doing this, but it could be done in a better way. You could add a field

```
private static DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

so it is initialized at startup.

Next you could add a field

```
private string logFilePath;
```

and a method `ComposeLogFilePath(DateTime)` like so

```
private static string ComposeLogFilePath(DateTime date)
{
    return Path.Combine(ConfigManager.GetAppSetting("logPath"), 
                             ("Log" + date.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd") + ".txt"));
}
```

which you then call from this constructor

```
static Logger()
{
    logFilePath = ComposeLogFilePath(currentDate);
}
```

By adding a method which checks if a change in the date has happened and if a new `logFilePath` needs to be composed like so

```
private static void CheckLogFileAndCreateIfNeeded()
{
    if (currentDate >= DateTime.Now.Date) { return; }  

    currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    logFilePath = ComposeLogFilePath(currentDate);
}
```

The method name is not the best, maybe you or some answerer will come up with a better one.

So each time the `Write()` method is called you call this method like so

```
public static void Write(string logMessage)
{
    try
    {
        CheckLogFileAndCreateIfNeeded();

        Log(logMessage, logFilePath);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        //log somewhere else if required
    }
}
```

which leads to the next point: Usually a `Logger` will log something so better change the names `Write()`-> `Log()` and `Log()` -> `Write()`.

> ```
> static void Log(string logMessage, string logFilePath)
> {
>     lock (_syncObject)
>     {
>         File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, 
>                     string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", 
>                     DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), logMessage));
>     }
> }
> ```

Here you should store `DateTime.Now` inside a variable to have the calls `ToLongTimeString()` and `ToLongTimeString()` using the same `DateTime` like so

```
static void Log(string logMessage, string logFilePath)
{
    lock (_syncObject)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, 
                    string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", 
                    date.ToLongTimeString(), date.ToLongDateString(), logMessage));
    }
}
```

Threadsafety is no issue here because of the `lock` **but** you could do this in a much better way by having a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in which you store the formatted message to log.

Then add a method to query the queue which ideally should spawn a thread to do the work. If there is already a thread running, you can just return from this method. If there is no thread running, start it and return.

By using a `ConcurrentQueue` you could get rid of the `lock` and you wouldn't need for each message to open the file.

Comment: I will look through your comments but please bear in mind I am beginner in .NET and don't give too advanced feedback. I will check your comments bit later.

Comment: What is the problem with the way I create files? I think it is easier to understand. It doesn't work you think? In my way if there is no file it will be created, if there is one, data will be apended

Comment: Let's say how you suggested composeLogFilePath etc. To sum up my approach was also working, just you suggested better performance? Or optimization did I get right? But functionally my approach is also working?

Comment: I understand but it maybe instead of config I will just pass the main path as property